# Is the JSlint warning `redeclaration of var counter` necessary?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have a script that's several lines long and I have a lot of flag types like so

```
var counter = 0;
var carFlags = {
 Audio : counter++ ,
 Bentley : counter++ ,
 Chrysler : counter++
 Datsun : counter++ 
 ...
};
```

later if I create a new flag object the same way

```
var counter = 0;
var nameFlags = {
 Ashley : counter++ ,
 Bronwyn : counter++ ,
 Catherine : counter++
 DakotaFanning : counter++ 
 ...
};
```

It complains that counter is used as part of a greater statement, but I think it's perfectly acceptable here. However, I have used counter twice here, so it warns of `redeclaration of var counter`. I could move `var counter` to the top of the page, but that might make it less clear what `counter` is used for. Is there any real problem with using var more than once? I had a `delete counter` statement but it did nothing. Should I change it to `delete window.counter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a problem.  In fact, in Javascript, variable declarations (with `var`) are automatically hoisted to the top of their enclosing scope anyway.  For example, the following:

```
var n = 5;
if (n < 3) {
   var q = 2;
   var n = 4;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
var q, n=5;
if (n < 3) {
   q = 2;
   n = 4;
}
```

Comment: So the then-branch of the if statement does not constitute a variable scope (like in C/C++)?

Comment: @StefanMajewsky Correct, variables in JavaScript are not scoped to code blocks like the then-branch of an if statement. JavaScript variables are scoped only to functions or the global scope.

Answer (score 3):

I am not quite sure about your scope here, but if it's global scope then `delete counter` would indeed do nothing. There is also no need to `delete window.counter` which will is the same thing anyway (if we are in a browser environment in global scope).

If you wish to re-use the variable - a simple assignment would do:

```
counter = 0
```

The reason JSLint complains is, I believe, to warn you that you might have meant to re-use the counter and accidentally typed `var` (happened to me more than once).

There is absolutely no harm in declaring the same variable twice (aside from increasing slightly the size of the JS file your users' browsers would have to download  when loading your page) *in the same scope*.

EDIT:

there is, of course, a question of why would you use the same name...

Answer (score 1):

Give them unique names and you won't have any problem.

```
var carCounter = 0;
var nameCounter = 0;
```

Nor will you end up with any hard to find bugs because you used the same variable for two different tasks.

Comment: good advice. But what if you have two (unnested) for loops, should you name one `var i`, and the other `var j`?